# Flutter InAppWebView (Version 6) Download Failed

Tags: flutter, android-webview, flutter-inappwebview

I'm working on my Graduation Project. I'm using exactly the same file_download example of InAppWebView version 6.0.0-beta.21 here:
https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples/tree/main/file_download

I tried to download files from the emulator, it doesn't work.
I tried to build the apk and install it on my phone (Android 10), and every time I download it says started then failed, here's a pic:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwhPH.jpg

Every time I build the apk it works, but it shows me some error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjb9x.png)

I DIDN'T change anything in the code at all..!
I'm running the sample project, I just downloaded the sample project ([here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples/tree/main/file_download))
I'm surprised that even the sample project didn't work. Could it be a problem from the side?
Help? Will appreciate it as I'm working on my Graduation Project.
**NOTE: I'm using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1**